# How much time for GPU quota updating?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying some stuff on Google Cloud and I have the following issue. Some days ago I created a Deep Learning VM with Compute Engine, with 8 vCPU and 1 Tesla K80 GPU. All worked fine, but now I want to try another GPU with different memory size. So, I deleted the VM instance (from Compute Engine -> VM instances) and I also deleted the deployment from Deployment manager. Nevertheless, when I try to create a new VM, I get an error message referring to the fact that I no more resources available and in fact, in the quotas page, I still see the GPU usage to 1 (with a limit of 1, that's why I can't create a new instance). Does anyone knows what could be the problem? Do I just have to wait? Thank you everyone!

Comment: What's the error message? This [document](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/troubleshooting#quota_exceeded) may works for your issue. 
If you use AI Platform Training, there are [special quota policies](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/quotas#gpu-quota) vary depending on resource. And if you're using the [Google Cloud free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial), you can't request a change to your quota.

Comment: In general it took 24-48 hrs

Comment: Hi @William, thanks for replying. The error message is as follows:  


`{"ResourceType":"compute.v1.instance","ResourceErrorCode":"ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED","ResourceErrorMessage":"The zone 'projects/mlai2020-exam-project/zones/us-west1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."}`  
I'm trying to instantiate a Deep Learning VM with Compute Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive a resource error (such as [ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability) or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your request.

This error is due to the availability of Compute Engine resources in the zone, So, you could try to create the resources in another zone in the region or in another region.
You can search another available zone on this document: [Available regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#available)

If possible, change the shape of the VM you are requesting. It's easier to get smaller machine types than larger ones. A change to your request, such as reducing the number of GPUs or using a custom VM with less memory or vCPUs, might allow your request to proceed.

Also, you can [create reservations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#creating_a_reservation) for Virtual Machine (VM) instances in a specific zone, using custom or predefined machine types, with or without additional GPUs or local SSDs, to ensure resources are available for your workloads when you need them.

Additionally, you can found more information to troubleshoot this issue in the following [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created)

Comment: Hi Jose, thanks for replying. I tried to follow your advice and changed the region several times, accordingly to the availabilities showed in the document you linked. Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error.

Comment: You mentioned that you wanted to try another GPU with different memory size: Could you please share the machine type you want to create? is it a [custom machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)?, What zones did you tried? Did you try  all the suggestions mentioned on [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#resource_availability)

Comment: Actually, after several tries I finally made it, so your suggestion was the right one. Thank you so much!